# Is there a word for the end of a bridge?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to say that someone is standing at the end of a bridge, waiting to meet someone else.

Is there a word for the end of the bridge, besides just 'end'?

I'm thinking something like a river's mouth.

Comment: According to several glossaries of bridge building terms, for a truss bridge at least, the "end" is called the ***[portal*](https://www.dot.state.oh.us/Divisions/Engineering/Structures/bridge%20operations%20and%20maintenance/PreventiveMaintenanceManual/BPMM/Glossary/p_terms.htm#portal)**: *the clear unobstructed space of a through truss bridge forming the entrance to the structure*. I googled `[anatomy of a bridge]` and according to some diagrams, the roadways leading up to the portal are known as the *approaches*. If I find something more satisfactory than this, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: We always called the close end "the foot" and the far end "the head" - I don't know why... I suppose it could be the other way 'round...

Comment: @Oldbag Because *the foot* is by your feet, obviously ;)

Comment: I think there are several different terms, depending on the type of bridge and where precisely you're talking about.  A small highway bridge has *abutments* on each side of each end.  (These are what cars run into when the driver is less than skillful at approaching the bridge.)  The sort of ramp leading onto the bridge is ofter referred to as (duh!) an "approach".  And I'm sure the civil engineers and highway department guys have all sorts of terms.

Comment: Okay, so my question for you, DC, is, would you ever use ***head***, apparently an OED-backed word? I probably never would. Knowing a technical or obscure word for something that in ordinarily life we call something else (*end*) sometimes serves little practical value. Reminds me of *[gore](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249780/what-do-you-call-this-segment-of-road-between-the-lane-and-an-exit/249782#249782)*, which I would never use. Also @ermanen

Comment: @pazzo: *Head* is not an obscure technical term, it is a common word for the end of a bridge.

Comment: A pier is a disappointed bridge.  James Joyce.

Comment: @pazzo As soon as I saw 'head' I recognized it as the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a ***head***.

> Either end of a bridge. *[OED]*

It is usually used as *head of the bridge*.

Another similar term is a *bridgehead*, which is mainly used as a military term, defined  in *OED* as a fortification covering or protecting the end of a bridge nearest the enemy. [Translation of French *tête de pont* : *tête*, head + *de*, of + *pont*, bridge.]

*[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bridgehead)* also gives another definition of *bridgehead*:

> The area immediately adjacent to the end of a bridge.

Comment: Nice find, man!

Comment: @DanBron: Thanks. "Head" is the natural way to say it but there can be technical terms like "portal" as you said. However, "portal" applies to covered bridges (like entering through a portal) and it can define the space between those supporters in technical contexts.

Comment: totally awesome, you rock!

Answer (score 1):

transpontine = far side of the bridge

> **transpontine** *adjective*:
>
> situated on the farther side of a bridge

([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transpontine))

Comment: Do you have a dictionary reference for this? Etymologically it sounds plausible, but I've never heard it actually used to refer to the end of a bridge.

Comment: Dictionary definition makes it sound like it's chiefly British. Does this actually get used?

Answer (score 0):

**Abutment** comes to mind.  From Wikipedia:

In engineering, abutment refers to the substructure at the ends of a bridge span or dam whereon the structure's superstructure rests or contacts. Single-span bridges have abutments at each end which provide vertical and lateral support for the bridge, as well as acting as retaining walls to resist lateral movement of the earthen fill of the bridge approach.

Comment: It's true that abutments are at the ends of bridges, but they're supporting the bridge. It's not where a person would stand, so it's not quite right.